# when using searchType = image on the API search explore no items resulted

Tags: google-apis-explorer

As of this morning (7/30/2020) my application that uses Google Search API stopped returning images results, after more in depth investigation with variety of tools ( cURL, Insomania, Postman etc ..) same results, when not using searchType = image ; results return, with image just metadata that also indicates multiple results, but the normal items[] array is not there.
Then I tried the same on Google's platform with the API explorer same behavior. What is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Now 8 hours later I tried again to execute a query with 'searchType=image" and it works; From my Angular application as well as Python script and the REST testing tools.
Also tested from the Google API explorer and now works like  a charm, as it always did.

I'm guessing Google had some downtime or server malfunction and then they fixed it.

Appreciate if anyone has confirmation of the scenario I'm suspecting